# SubmitChanges() não atualiza os dados no Linq

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

```
internal bool AlterarCargo(string login, string Categoria)
{
    db.Log = Console.Out; //tentei ativar para ver se encontrava o erro mas não ajudou nada.
    var categoria = from x in db.Categorias
                    where x.Categorias == Categoria
                    select x.Id_Categorias;

    var Id_Inscricao = from x in db.DadosPessoaisComuns
            where x.login == login
            select x.Id_Inscricao;

    var query = from x in db.DadosCategorias
                where x.Id_Inscricao == Convert.ToInt16(Id_Inscricao.First())
                select x;

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        item.Id_Categorias = categoria.First();
        MessageBox.Show(item.Id_Categorias.ToString() + "  " + item.Id_Inscricao.ToString());  // mostra os dados já atualizados
    }

    db.SubmitChanges();

    return true;
}
```

Quando consulto a base de dados os dados não foram atualizados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema encontrava-se na base de dados.
Embora não ocorre-se erro no visual studio o problema é que não tinha o modelo actualizado com o da base de dados.